# Return value of static variable from inline function

Tags: c++, c

```
static inline JGPlatformInfo* currentPlatform(){
    static JGPlatformInfo* platform = nil;

    if (platform == nil){
        JGPlatformInfo info = supportedPlatform();
        platform = &info;
    }

    return platform;    
}
```

I am getting inconsistent results with this code (C family) The value of `platform` changes for no reason and the memory appears to be correct. What could be causing this? Could the `inline` keyword be affecting this?

Comment: I have no idea about objective-c but in C and C++ storing an address of a local variable in a static variable and returning such address from the function is a very very bad idea

Comment: Please pick a language. Is this C, C++, or objective-C?

Comment: @Maciej Hehl, it's no different in Objective-C.

Comment: @Maciej: True that would cause unpredictable results as the pointer would be invalid, yet it would not be NULL.

Comment: -1 for not picking a language; over-tagging gets more attention but wastes our time.

Comment: @potatoswatter It is listed at the bottom of the question, and the concept is not language specific.

Comment: @potatoswatter I would have to agree with the tags Justin used. If you read the whole thing, you'd see he mentioned that it's in an Objective-C program. Since Objective-C is a superset of C, it makes sense to have C as a tag as well. And as someone pointed out below, a possible solution could be programmed in C++. I think he tagged it very appropriately.

Comment: @Ryan: He added the note about Objective-C after I'd already written the C++ answer below. Look at the chronology if you're really interested. The assumption that "the concept should be the same" is wrong.

Comment: The concepts are obviously **not** the same in the different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables you defined are always temporary. That means when you leave scope your variable is going to get destroyed and the pointer to it will be invalid (or worse: it will point to a valid location that it shouldn't point to). This is where dynamic allocation comes into hand. Here's how I would achieve the same effect that you are going for:

In your source file:

```
JGPlatformInfo* gCurrentPlatform = NULL;
```

If you really want this function inline, put this in your header file:

```
extern JGPlatformInfo* gCurrentPlatform;

...

// I'm not too familiar with C, but it seems like adding static
// to an inline function would be redundant
inline JGPlatformInfo* currentPlatform()
{
    if (!gCurrentPlatform)
    {
        gCurrentPlatform = malloc(sizeof(JGPlatformInfo));
        *gCurrentPlatform = supportedPlatform();
    }

    return gCurrentPlatform;
}
```

`malloc(x)` allocates x bytes of memory and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: Um, no -- static variables are NOT temporary, they have static storage duration (so are created when the process starts and persist as long as the process does).

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ah yes, I posted this ages ago. I think the actual problem is that `platform` is a static variable, and static variables will have different symbols for each translation unit (or at least, the inlined function will, which will throw it off in the same way). If Justin is defining this function in an include header, which I assume he does because he mentions it is inlined, then each version of the function (generated by each compilation unit) will have a different version of `platform`. Making `platform` a global will fix this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you have that in a header file, right? Then each translation unit will have its own copy of the `platform` variable.

Now for something completely different - the **real** problem: you are returning an address of an automatic variable - i.e. a pointer into some stack frame - that's broken.

Comment: Which programming language are you answering about?

Comment: A function scope `static` is just like a `class`-scope `static`: there is only one variable in the program.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4111/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nikolai-n-fetissov)

Comment: "don't really do chats" Whatever, it's just that the system proposed me to open a chat. (I am new to this site.)

Comment: "_And what happens when that function gets inlined into two translation units?_" It is the compiler job to make it work.
 
Inlining is just an optimisation, and should not affect program semantic.

Comment: Almost your own words: "For <ins>inline</ins>function<del>-scope statics</del> the declaration is the definition, so you end up with as many definitions as there are including translation units. And that is a clear violation of the language rules (the "one definition" rule to be exact)."

Comment: You said: "_For function-scope statics the declaration is the definition, so you end up with as many definitions as there are including translation units. And that is a clear violation of the language rules (the "one definition" rule to be exact). _" This is not correct WRT C++.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what's causing this issue, but the usual (simpler, safer, idiomatic) way to do this is:

```
inline JGPlatformInfo &currentPlatform() {
    // supportedPlatform() will only be called once
    static JGPlatformInfo platform = supportedPlatform();

    return platform; // & platform would work if you must return a pointer
}
```

I suspect the reason for your immediate problem is that qualifying the function as `static` causes the compiler to create a separate instance of the variable for every translation unit. It wasn't returning to `NULL` for every function call, but only on the first call from each `.cpp` file.

Comment: At least in C (I am not sure of the situation in C++), the initialiser for a variable with static storage duration cannot include a function call - it must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @caf: in C++ it may include a function call, and as I said this is idiomatic. I didn't notice the C tag.

Comment: @caf - in C++ initializer of a static variable *is* a function call - a constructor.

Comment: @Justin: Once again, what language are you using?

Comment: @Justin: Sorry, I didn't see the edit. This solution requires C++.

Answer (score 3):

With the C99 version of inline functions, an `inline` function is not allowed to declare variables with static storage duration - doing so invokes undefined behaviour.

You must make the variable an `extern` and define it in one translation unit.

Answer (score -1):

Cause inline function will be expanded at every place you use it.
So in fact there will be many static platform in your codes.
You should remove "inline", and don't try to return address of temp variables.

Comment: That depends on the language he eventually settles for. In C++ it is entirely legal to have static variables in inline functions. The compiler has to make sure they all refer to a single object.

Comment: Inlining is an optimisation. Declaring a function `inline` does make it a macro, not even close.